# python error in deleting db file

Tags: python, windows, sqlite, pycharm

Hello I learning python using pycharm and following one small youtube series where I want to delete .db file from project folder. but I am getting an error that states java.io.IOException. Please suggest what is the main problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the full traceback, this could be a number of things

Comment: Show your code and the directory structure.